# How to mock e2e tests in angular 6

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, angular6

I'm trying mock the httpClient requests, but I don't know how to do this.

I was search for answers and I found this module: [ng-apimock](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock).
Seems that is used to mock http requests when you make the e2e tests. If you have an example to show, please put the link here.

I read this [README](https://github.com/mdasberg/ng-apimock/blob/master/ANGULAR_CLI.md) that explain how to implement this module in angular 2+ project, but it was not clear to me how to implement.

Can someone explain how mock my e2e tests in angular 6?

Comment: What do you mean *"mock e2e tests"*? The whole point of end-to-end testing is that it's end-to-end; you *aren't* mocking.

Comment: @jonrsharpe
I would like to mock, for example, the requests http when I log in system.
I did not want to depend on the server to run the end-to-end tests. I just wanted to respond with a 200 status, for example.

Comment: Then I'd recommend standing up an external mock server. I've used Drakov, for example.

Comment: Do you use Drakov with angular 6? 
If yes, can you show me an example of the integration of the angular with the drakov?

Comment: What do you mean "with" and "integration"? It's an *external* mock server, you can use it with any other thing making HTTP requests. Equally you could use any other thing that can receive and respond to those requests as your mock.

Comment: So what is the difference between to test with local server and to test with an external mock server?
For example, in angularJs, we can use protractor to mock the http requests. Protractor and angular work together. However, in angular 6, protractor doesn't work to mock http requests.